# <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >Request Info</button></form>

Tags: javascript, html

How do I redirect the Request info button on-click to a new page. I am currently capturing emails with this button, but I would like to capture emails and redirect on the same click.

```
**<form action="subscribe.php" class="form-inline" method="POST">
<input class="form-control " name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="Email"/>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >
Request Info
</button>
</form>**
```

Comment: 2 options: you can do it on the php side, or do an ajax request and redirect upon success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a **header()** redirect in the **subscribe.php** script on server side.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

**subscribe.php:**

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```